# ExtJS 3: Two ways of creating custom class: what's the difference?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I'm trying to learn ExtJS and object-oriented JavaScript in general. I've seen people defining classes in custom namespaces in a couple of ways. What's the difference between these two methods?

**Method 1**

```
Ext.ns('myapp.cars');
(function(){
    var Car = Ext.extend(Object, {
       //...
    })

    myapp.cars.Car = Car;
})()
```

**Method 2**

```
Ext.ns('myapp.cars');
myapp.cars.Car = Ext.extend(Object, {
       //...
});
```

Method 2 is easier to read and requires less code; is there any reason Method 1 is better? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that Method 2 is easier to read and requires less code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's basically the same, except that you could use private variables in the self-exectuing function of the first method, while you can only define global variables in the second one.

For example:

```
Ext.ns('myapp.cars');
(function(){

    var carInfo = {
      goodEngine: true
    };

    var Car = Ext.extend(Object, {
       info: carInfo
    });

    myapp.cars.Car = Car;
})()

// carInfo is undefined here, so this will give an error
alert( carInfo.goodEngine );
```

So, the first method is quite useful if you work with a bunge of variables that you won't use later on.

Comment: This is my favorite implementation of the pattern, although I'm having trouble with one thing... @Harmen I have one question, if I'm extending an Ext class, for example `var MyWindowClass = Ext.extend(Ext.Window, { ... });`

Do you know how I can use default configs declared in `MyWindowClass` and then, if I extend further (i.e. `var MySuperWindowClass = Ext.extend(myapp.MyWindowClass , { ... });`) declare default configs again that will be applied along with the default configs in MyWindowClass ?

Answer (score 6):

The following are practically equivalent:

```
var Car = Ext.extend(Object, {
   //...
});

myapp.cars.Car = Car;
```

... and:

```
myapp.cars.Car = Ext.extend(Object, {
   //...
});
```

In the first example you'd be using a temporary variable to hold a reference to the newly created object, which is then copied to `myapp.cars.Car` (the reference is copied, not the object). In the second example you'd be assigning the reference to the object directly to `myapp.cars.Car`.

The reason your first example was enclosed in the self-invoking anonymous function `(function(){ })()` is to limit the scope of that temporary variable. That is generally done in order not to pollute the global namespace with that `Car` variable. If there was an other `Car` variable defined elsewhere, it would not conflict with this one. Example:

```
var Car = "My Nice Car";

(function(){
    var Car = Ext.extend(Object, {
       //...
    });

    myapp.cars.Car = Car;
})();

alert(Car); // Still "My Nice Car"
            // No conflict with the `Car` variable in the self invoking function.
```